# SPF "permerror" from Google, IPv6 failure?

Tags: dns, spf

Without IPv6 entry in my SPF record, I get softfails if the other server uses IPv6. However when I add a ip6 record (which is my accurate address, with a reverse DNS entry) I get a permerror. I cannot figure out what the issue is.

From email header:

> Received-SPF: permerror (google.com: domain of sjacobs@watershedmg.org
>   uses a mechanism not recognized by this client. unknown  mechanisms:
>   )) client-ip=2600:3c01::f03c:91ff:fe6e:85d7

My full SPF record:

> v=spf1 mx ptr ip4:173.255.244.150 ip6:22600:3c01::f03c:91ff:fe6e:85d7
>   a:watershedmg.org include:_spf.google.com ~all

Can anyone shed light on this? Thank you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`22600:3c01::f03c:91ff:fe6e:85d7` is not a valid IPv6 address.  Check the first section - it's got too many digits.  It looks like you added an extra '2'

You also don't need the `mx` since you're using Google Apps for your email.  So a better version of this record would be

> v=spf1 ip4:173.255.244.150 ip6:2600:3c01::f03c:91ff:fe6e:85d7
>   include:_spf.google.com a:watershedmg.org ~all

and the `a` directive is only necessary if you've got a web server that is directly sending email using a local mail server.  Otherwise you should remove it as well.

Comment: Thank you, Peter! Yes, somehow copy and paste failed me.

We are actually sending out from a Debian server with Postfix... after reading so many posts I still am unclear whether I need the a:watershedmg.org and if I should only include mx and not ptr and a.

Right now I have 
v=spf1 mx a ptr ip4:173.255.244.150 ip6:2600:3c01::f03c:91ff:fe6e:85d7 include:_spf.google.com ~all

Comment: So `ptr` is generally not recommended.  If the IP of the Debian server is fixed, I'd just include an appropriate ip4 or ip6 directive.  If not, and the server has a known name, I'd use an `a` directive.  The `mx` won't help you, since your MX servers are Google Apps servers, handled by the `include:_spf.google.com`

Comment: OK... interesting. So it sounds like I don't need `a`,`ptr`, or `mx`. If I'm understanding, `v=spf1 ip4:173.255.244.150 ip6:2600:3c01::f03c:91ff:fe6e:85d7 include:_spf.google.com ~all` is all I need. Thank you very much for your help!